# Set hidden form field values with JavaScript but request still empty

Tags: javascript, forms

I try to set some hidden form field values with an onclick event.
Ok, after I did something like this:

```
document.getElementById('hidden_field').value = 123;
```

I can output the value with the firebug console by entering this:

```
alert(document.getElementById('hidden_field').value);
```

So the values are definitely set. But now when I submit the form, the hidden field values are still empty.

Do you have any idea whats going wrong?

Comment: You will need to post your HTML

Comment: Check if your 'hidden_field' is inside the form element, it contains name and id attributes and form is posted correctly.

Comment: You can install something like TamperData to see what's in the actual HTTP request/response blocks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make sure your hidden field has the `name` attribute:

```
<input id="hidden_field" name="hidden_field" type="hidden" value="123" />
```

Inputs without a `name` attribute aren't sent with the request.

Comment: And note also (this is for the OP Andy, not you :-) that your `<input>` can have *both* "id" and "name" attributes, and if desired the values of those attributes can be the same. Only one element on a given page can have a particular "id" value, however.

Comment: @Pointy: even though the comment wasn't directed at me, you made a good point and I edited my answer to reflect that, using the id given in the example by the OP :-)

Comment: Thank all of you for your quick answer :)

I use the symfony php framework. In the template there was a method that renders all hidden fields automatically. And I did it by hand, too. So one field was filled the other not. Now it work, thx.